# Casting error in BST iterator

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with casting for generics. What I'm trying to do is use a generic iterator to help me print out what is in my Binary Search Tree. However the for loop I'm implementing says their are incompatible types and therefore will not run. Wanted to get some insight on to what I'm doing wrong here.

```
public class BinarySearchTree<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> implements Iterable{...}

public class MainBST { 

    public <AnyType> void print(BinarySearchTree<? extends AnyType> t ) { 

        for(AnyType x : t) //incompatible type
            System.out.print(x + ", "); 

             System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your class really just implement `Iterable`, or does it implement `Iterable<AnyType>`? It sounds like it should be the latter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `BinarySearchTree` declaration. It's implementing the *raw* `Iterable` type, when it should be implementing `Iterable<AnyType>`. With the raw `Iterator` type, the code using the enhanced-for loop only knows that the values will be compatible with `Object` - so you could change your loop to `for (Object x : t)` but of course that's not what you really want.

I've reproduced the compile-time error you've shown, and then fixed it by changing the declaration to:

```
class BinarySearchTree<AnyType extends Comparable<? super AnyType>> 
    implements Iterable<AnyType> {
    ...
}
```

(And then changing the `iterator` method to return `Iterator<AnyType>` of course.)